# Маппинг данных одной таблицы на разные классы по условию

Tags: php, postgresql, php7, symfony4, doctrine-orm

У меня в таблице 2 сущности - группы и подгруппы, у групп и подгрупп разные свойства. Нет возможности изменить структуру таблицы потому что переписываю старый проект, и может другое сломаться

База postgreSql

Можно ли как-то эти сущности доктриной смапить на разные объекты?

Answer (score 0):

Собственно нашел два решения:

1. [Наследование](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)
2. Сделать представление в базе

Я выбрал 2 вариант так как он был проще для меня